# What does "at least it's in tens, singles and coins" mean in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It's from a Children's book.
Seven men was splitting 10,000 dollars, but they don't want fractions.
//Transcript:

> All seven men took 1000 dollars each which was 7000 dollars. that left 3000 dollars on the table.
>
> "how do we split three thousand between seven?" asked big Pocky."do we need fractions yet?"
>
> "No way!"said Blade."We split it into hundreds and share them out, and luckily we've got the right guy to work it out. How many do we get, Numbers?
>
> The smallest of the men had a quick thing."three thousand is thirty hundreds. We can take four hundred each, and that leaves two hundred on the table."
>
> "At least it's in tens, singles and coins."said Porky."How many tens do we get each, Numbers"
>
> "Two,"Said Numbers.
> //

Does the "tens singles and coins"mean tens, units and 0.1? Why did Porky say "at least it's in ……" I don't get the point.

Comment: Ten-dollar bills, one-dollar bills (singles) and various coins smaller than 1 dollar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

200 left on the table would not be able to be split if there were two hundred dollar bills.

So Porky points that out.

If Porky spoke his full thoughts, they would be: "oh no, we still have more left over, well at least it is in smaller units of ten dollar bills, one dollar bills, and coins so we can split the money further. Now that we split the hundreds, lets split the tens, how many tens do we get?"